# How to enable GIT support in TFS 2012 Update 2 (self-hosted)

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

We have TFS 2012 installed with Update 2 but I cannot figure out if Git support is included and how to create a team project using Git instead of TFS version control.  Is Git support only available via tfs.visualstudio.com or is it in all TFS 2012 Update 2 installations?  Do I need to install something separate to the server to get Git to work?  I installed TFS tools for Git locally but I still don't see how to create a Git Team Project so we can use TFS with our Mac work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not.  It is available today in the (cloud hosted) Team Foundation *Service* and [will be included in the next major version of (on-premises) Team Foundation *Server*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx), TFS 2013, which is [scheduled to be released by the end of the year](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/19/enterprise-grade-git.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is going to release a preview of TFS 2013 next week which includes the on-premise Git support. The preview is marked as go-live so you should be able to use it in production without major issues.

See [Brian Harry's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/19/enterprise-grade-git.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Richard, will keep an eye out for it.